# Compiling php-7 from source gives recipe for target 'libphp7.la' failed

Tags: php, build-process, libtool, php-7

I was compiling PHP-7.0.1 from source with the following configurations:

```
$ ./configure -q \
--prefix=/opt/php/php-7.0 \
--bindir=/opt/php/php-7.0/bin --sbindir=/opt/php/php-7.0/bin \
--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs \
--enable-zip --enable-pdo \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--enable-calendar --enable-mysqlnd-compression-support \
--enable-embedded-mysqli --enable-mbregex \
--enable-bcmath --with-xsl \
--enable-sockets --with-tidy \
--enable-cli --enable-pcntl --with-mcrypt \
--with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-pear \
--enable-shared
```

The above finished successfully. Later, I run a `make && make test` giving me the following error:

> libtool: link: `ext/xmlwriter/php_xmlwriter.lo' is not a valid libtool
>   object
>
> Makefile:146: recipe for target 'libphp7.la' failed make: ***
>   [libphp7.la] Error 1

The lines 145-147 in `Makefile` are:

```
libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).la: $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS)
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) -rpath $(phptempdir) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(PHP_RPATHS) $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS) $(EXTRA_LIBS) $(ZEND_EXTRA_LIBS) -o $@
    -@$(LIBTOOL) --silent --mode=install cp $@ $(phptempdir)/$@ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What could be the issue here?

---

### EDIT

Contents of `ext/xmlwriter/php_xmlwriter.lo`:

```
pic_object='.libs/php_xmlwriter.o'

# Name of the non-PIC object.
non_pic_object=none
```

---

### EDIT-2

The entire output, including the `./configure` command is available on [hastebin](http://www.hastebin.com/awifucacer.coffee) as requested [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394514/compiling-php-7-from-source-gives-recipe-for-target-libphp7-la-failed#comment56894666_34394514). The output is the same as before when `xmlwriter` is not disabled:

```
┌─[hjpotter92]─(php-7.0.1)─[12:48 pm] 
└──% make >> ~/out 
libtool: link: `ext/xmlwriter/php_xmlwriter.lo' is not a valid libtool object
make: *** [libphp7.la] Error 1
```

Comment: a) Does the file `ext/xmlwriter/php_xmlwriter.lo` exist? b) If yes, what it it's contents? c) Does the build complete if you disable the xmlwriter extension?

Comment: @VolkerK a) Yes. b) Added to question. c) Yes. (`make test` is taking forever, but make completed succcessfully)

Comment: @hjpotter92 If this solved your problem, please answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Will But it didn't. VolkerK just suggested that I disable one of the extensions. While that does build the package successfully, it doesn't show/explain what was causing the problem. Whereas, compiling PHP5, with that extension enabled, does not cause any problems at all.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Would you mind uploading your entire build output, from `./configure` until the end? Perhaps put it on PasteBin and link it here in the comments? Also, is there sufficient disk space remaining on your system? The cause of the errors is not to be found in what we already have in your post... I have a feeling something went wrong earlier in the build; perhaps a missing dependency.

Comment: @Will http://www.hastebin.com/awifucacer

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, all I did to fix it was:

```
make clean
```

and then:

```
make
```

Even though my package was unzipped and ./configure'd for the first time, running "make clean" does make a huge difference.

works fine!